# Processing 3 Box2D Velocity Not Scaling With Resolution

Tags: processing, box2d, game-physics, pixel, screen-resolution

I'm currently trying to make my simple game scale with the resolution.  I've noticed though when I change the resolution not everything works out.  For instance from the shift from 1280x720 to 1920x1080 the jumping distance changes slightly.  The main problem I've noticed is that when I fire a projectile with a velocity.  On lower resolutions it seems to travel across the screen significantly faster and I can't understand why as it should scale down with the size of the window.  Here is a snipet of the code that fires a projectile:

```
m = new Box(l.pos.x+Width/32*direction2, l.pos.y-Height/288, Width/64, Height/72, true, 4);
              m.body.setGravityScale(0f);
              boxes.add(m);
              m.body.setLinearVelocity(new Vec2(Width*direction2, 0));
```

In this scenario m is a box I'm creating.  In new Box(spawn x coordinate, spawn y cooridinate, width of box, height of box, is the box moveable, type of box)  l.pos.x and l.pos.y are the positions I'm firing the box from.  The Height and Width variables are the size of the current window in pixels being updated in void draw(), direction2 is either 1 or -1 depending on the direction in which the character is facing.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell how the rest of code affects the simulation without seeing more of it.

Ideally you would want to keep phyics related properties independent from the Processing sketch dimensions in terms of dimensions but maintain proportion so you can simply scale up the rendering of the same sized world. If you have mouse interaction the coordinates would scale as well, but other than the position, the rest of physical proeprties should be maintained.

From what I can gather in your code if `Width` is the sketch's `width` you should de-couple that from linear velocity:

```
m.body.setLinearVelocity(new Vec2(Width*direction2, 0));
```

you should use a value that you will keep constant in relation to the sketch dimensions.